# React native build failed with error Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Iam using ubuntu . When i do npx react-native run-android it fails and outputs me

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong:
>   Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
>   Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().

> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 912ms

and my react-native doctor output is :

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the setup guide: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup ?

Comment: yes i did . I tried again and again i think its the problem with environmental variables .

Comment: What shell are you using? Does `echo $ANDROID_HOME` display anything?